# Hotkey with MouseKeyHook not catching event in C#

Tags: c#, systray, mousekeyhook

I'm building a word lookup application that runs in system tray and when you scan a block of a few words and then press a hotkey combination like Shift + C + V for example.

However, the problem is that when I test it on my personal machine, it works fine. But when through Tester's machine, it is not possible to catch the hotkey press event.

I'm using MouseKeyHook's library.

May everyone help you

Here is my code

```
enum KeyModifier
{
    None = 0,
    Alt = 1,
    Control = 2,
    Shift = 4
}
public Main()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    myProcess.PriorityClass = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.High;

    InitializeComponent();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    notify.Visible = true;

    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.Padding = new Padding(borderSize);
    this.panel1.BackColor = borderColor;
    this.BackColor = borderColor;

    if (File.Exists("hotkey.txt") == false)
    {
        string noidung = "Shift+F";

        File.WriteAllText("hotkey.txt", noidung);
    }

    manage = new ManageDictionary();

    conn = ConnectDB.Connect();

    ctrl = new ControlData(m_Events, data, txtSearch);

    ctrl.SubscribeGlobal();

    resetHotKey();
}


public void resetConnection()
{
    conn = ConnectDB.Connect();
}
public void resetHotKey()
{
    string[] hot;
    string key;
    this.hotkey_Events = Hook.GlobalEvents();
    if (File.Exists("hotkey.txt"))
    {
        hot = File.ReadAllLines("hotkey.txt");
        key = hot[0];
    }
    else
    {
        key = "Shift+F";
    }
    var subhotkey = Combination.FromString(key);

    Action action = () => {
        string keyword = Clipboard.GetText().Trim();
        if (keyword.Equals(""))
            return;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            ArrayList re;
            re = manage.findWord(conn, keyword);

            if (re.Count == 0)
            {
                Dictionary a = new Dictionary(0, "Không tìm thấy kết quả", "", "", "", "");
                re.Add(a);
                Notification noti = new Notification(re, keyword);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                noti.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                Notification noti = new Notification(re, keyword);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                noti.Show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Kết nối thất bại");
        }
        conn.Close();
    };

    var assignment = new Dictionary<Combination, Action>
    {
        {subhotkey, action}
    };

    this.hotkey_Events.OnCombination(assignment);
    
}
```

Comment: MouseKeyHook is often treated as malware by security software. Does your friend have a security scanning product? That would be my guess!

Comment: I'm not sure anymore. Is there any way to fix it?
Only the tester's machine has that problem

Comment: Does it work when running as admin maybe?

Comment: of course, when i package the app it runs normally until using hotkey combination will shut down the app and throw an exception